# About Admin Side I have a template file in which I have a form submission

Tags: magento2, redirect, admin-controller

In the admin side, I have a template file in which I have  a form submission.

On form submission, an action would be executed, but it is redirecting to dashboard.

can anyone have any idea, how to overcome this kind of problem in magento 2

Comment: This problem occurs mainly due to an invalid action url given in the form. Please check your form action and make sure your action controller is executed. Put a die('hit the controller action') inside your controller action.

Comment: i have controller for action but it is not even called when form submitted @MGento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgot to add form key to the form:

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

Or

```
<?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
```

Comment: But in block i should have getFormKey() in order to use in my template file,

Comment: it have used in admin backend setting secure url Off to formkey @Khoa TruongDinh

Comment: @PranayK we need to add the form key to form.

Comment: `it have used in admin backend setting secure url Off to formkey`: where is this option config?

Comment: Thanks It is Working @Khoa TruongDinh after placing this in template <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>

Answer (score 1):

write code in your block

```
public function __construct(

    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context  

    array $data = array()
    ) {
    $this->formKey = $context->getFormKey();

    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getFormKey() {

        return $this->formKey->getFormKey();
}
```

Comment: it is throwing an error

Comment: please provide me error in more detail also clear var/generation and check.